# Properly Securing GAE Task Queue URLs (without using app.yaml)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, task-queue, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I want to secure my Task Queue URLs against malicious access.

In the views that the Task Queue requests I've got:

```
if not users.is_current_user_admin():
    return HttpResponse(status=403)
```

But my Task Queues are receiving 403 errors! I was under the impression from [this GAE documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html#Securing_URLs_for_Tasks) that the Task Queue user was gauranteed to be an admin. What gives?

**NOTE:** I'm using DjangoNonRel so I can't specify the admin only url access in my `app.yaml`, I have to do it programmatically in the views.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tasks can bypass `login: admin` restrictions, however `users.is_current_user_admin()` will still return false, as there is technically no current user.

Using Django-nonrel shouldn't stop you from protecting your tasks with app.yaml. Just add a protected handler above your Django catch-all:

```
handlers:    

- url: /tasks/.+
  script: main.py
  login: admin

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Any URLs that start with /tasks/ will be accessible to the task queue and inaccessible to non-admin visitors, without changing how anything routes.

Comment: Nice. That's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your handlers can look for a task queue HTTP header, such as X-AppEngine-QueueName.

From official [GAE docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#task_request_headers) :

Requests from the Task Queue service contain the following HTTP headers:

> X-AppEngine-QueueName
>   X-AppEngine-TaskName
>   X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount
>   X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount
>   X-AppEngine-TaskETA
>
> These headers are set internally by Google App Engine. **If your
>   request handler finds any of these headers, it can trust that the
>   request is a Task Queue request.**  If any of the above headers are
>   present in an external user request to your app, they are stripped.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by doing 2 checks

- Check remote address, it will be `0.1.0.1`
- Check for existence of header [**X-Appengine-Cron**].

This will secure you Task Queue URLs (this is only applicable for Pull Queues as per my knowledge).

I wrote a decorator which does this checks for me.Hope this was helpful

For more info, Please refer [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron)